# Type checking Problems

Tags: c#

I want A to contain a variable of Type B.
However on assigning a value to that varaible I want to check if it is an instance of a certain subclass of B.

```
public class A  {

    public System.Type acceptedType;

    public B target;

    public A(System.Type t1){
        this.acceptedType = t1;
    }

    public bool connect(B b1){
        if(b1 is this.acceptedType){
            this.target = b1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However I get:

> Unexpected symbol 'this', expecting 'type'

Is 'System.Type' the wrong variable type or am I just misunderstanding the 'is' operator?

Comment: `if(b1 is typeof(this.acceptedType))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work:

```
Foo fooObj = new Foo();
Foo fooObj2 = new Foo();
if (fooObj is fooObj2) // will not work
```

Why? Because `is` requires a type, NOT an instance. So this will work:

```
if (fooObj is Foo)
```

**Edit**

Here is how you can do what you want to do:

```
Type fooType = typeof(String);
if (fooType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Will not show.");
}

if (fooType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This will show.");
}
```

[<== Fiddle With Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w7bhdX)

Comment: I thought that the variable 'acceptedType' would contain a type and not just an instance. If 'System.type' is not the right variable type to store a type what type should the variable be?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured it out. 
Instead of:

```
if(b1 is this.acceptedType)
```

I now use:

```
if(this.acceptedType.IsInstanceOfType(b1))
```

And it seems to behave how I want it to.
Thank you for pointing out where my Mistake was!